# WebGUI on D-Link switch not accessible

Tags: networking, switch

I am looking for an advice regarding the D-Link DES 1250G switch. This switch has no console port and the only way to get access to it is via Utility application, where very little configuration can be made or Web based GUI interface.

I have proceeded with the manual and set IP address on the PC to static IP matching the IP range on the switch, but when trying to access Web GUI I am getting IIS server splash screen which redirects me to iis.net webpage. Hence I am not able to get to the configuration of it.

Is there any way I could get the Web GUI working?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Have you tried from an XP machine? it doesn't even use https so a modern browser may not find it. Basically it was designed to be accessed by 2004 technology, so that's what I'd use. Manual, for anyone else who wants to have a look -https://eu.dlink.com/uk/en/-/media/business_products/des/des-1250g/manual/des-1252_manual_en_uk.pdf Discontinued 2009.

Comment: If you are getting an IIS splash screen, that sounds more like you are trying to access your own PC rather than the switch. Set your IP address to 192.168.0.200 and access the switch at 192.168.0.1. You might have to use Firefox and set security.tls.version.enable-deprecated to true in about:config of Firefox to access it. You may also have to disconnect every other device connected to the switch except your laptop so as to eliminate any possible IP address conflicts.

Comment: As @acejavelin said, if you're seeing an IIS page, you're not accessing the switch. To see what is going on, add the IP configuration of the switch and the PC to the question, and also add the url of the webpage you're trying to access.

Comment: The switch has a modified IP address, I used the Smart Console switch "web GUI" button, which opened a browser with switch IP, which is 52.183.43.226, I have set my PC static address to 52.183.43.25. I did run IP Angry scanner and nmap, which showed me that only this switch is having above IP address.

Answer (score 0):

> when trying to access Web GUI I am getting IIS server splash screen which redirects me to iis.net webpage.

If that's the address you set the switch to, there's an address collision. You're seeing the other device's web page.

Disconnect everything from the switch but your PC. Then try again. If it doesn't work right away, wait for ~30 seconds to age out the wrong ARP entry in the local cache.

If you succeed in reaching the switch's GUI make sure you set it to a different, unused IP address as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I unplugged all devices and internet connection from the switch, set my PC to a Static IP address to match the IP range on the switch, then used Edge browser with http:// at the beginning. It helped. The shame is, there is a password set ages ago which I don't know. Nothing from usual and manufacturer works. Password reset would delete all the settings with it, so...Went through the whole tutorial for this model.